# How can I send mail to an unknown amount of email addresses in PHP? (Referral Form)

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm trying to write a custom referral form. A user can submit up to 10 emails maximum, and must have at least one entered.

I'm using a POST method for my form. If a user enters 3 emails (or 5, or 7, or 9, etc...), how can I get all of those?

Also, I'm using JavaScript to add/delete the fields. Not that it matters, because they all have an id that has a number appended to the end. (For example, tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4, etc. etc.)

Here's my HTML: http://www.graphicgoldfish.com/

To get an idea of what I'm going for.

PHP:

```
$from = $_POST["tf_from"];
$r_char_name = $_POST["tf_character"];
$r_ign = $_POST["tf_ign"];

$contacts = array();

foreach($contacts as $contact) {
    $to = $contact;
    $subject = "Check out this server!"
    $message = "http://www.arithia.com"
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

That's all I've got so far in my PHP. :(

EDIT: I'm aware that I can use a bunch of conditionals, btw... (If the field is not empty, send the email), but I'm sure there's a better way of doing this, and I'd just like to know. ^_^

Comment: We need to see an example output of what the emails entered look like. Are they based on a comma seperated method, a newline method, other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each email `input` tag need a `name` attribute, for example:

```
<input type="email" name="emails[]" id="..">
```

In PHP, it will be parsed into an array automatically when `name` ends with `[]`.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < min(count($_POST['emails']), 10); $i++) {
  $email = $_POST['emails'][$i];
  // send email
}
```